# TextBox receiving focus when clicking on ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I'm struggling to make a custom autocomplete style control for my application using a list view. In one form, the custom control is working as expected, however in another, when clicking on the ListView, rather than the ListViewItem being selected, the first TextBox in the form is selected instead.

Rather than clog up the question with a wall of code, here is the code for the [AutoCompleteListView](https://gist.github.com/robertjawoods/7847309034da55201115c177afe827db).

Here is an image of the form. Items are redacted due to data protection:
[image: Form image]

Also, [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/nqyEhBuwYaAQMoxybv/giphy.gif) is a .gif showing the behaviour of the form. What I'm doing in the aformentioned gif is attempting to click on the first item within the ListView, however, as I do that, focus changes to the first text box in the form. This same behaviour occurs when clicking on any item, in any of the 3 text boxes.

I have attempted to trace the events using RuntimeFlow to watch as events fire, but it has not provided any clarity as to what is actually happening. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is in ItemClick you are setting visibility to false, which means something else in the form needs focus, ie the textbox. So do a textbox.focus() in ItemClick to the desired textbox. And given that you will not have access to the parent form in this class, I recommend you make an OnClose event in the AutoCompleteListView and subscribe to it in the parent form, to set the focus to somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've created an "OnClose" event handler, a Hide() method that sets Visible = false, and then invokes the OnClose event for on the control. The hide method is called once a ListItem is clicked. In the parent form, I am subscribed to the events for each of them. The parent form calls `textBox.Focus();` for their respective TextBox controls. However, the ItemClick event only seems to be firing for the item at index 0, so any subsequent items clicked on will not fire the "ItemClicked" event

Comment: Strongly suspect it has something to do with `ListViewItem item = this?.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);` investigate with a breakpoint.